# Is there an equivalent to memcpy() that works inside a CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to break apart and reshape the structure of an array asynchronously using the CUDA kernel. `memcpy()` doesn't work inside the kernel, and neither does `cudaMemcpy()`*; I'm at a loss.

Can anyone tell me the preferred method for copying memory from within the CUDA kernel?

**It is worth noting, `cudaMemcpy(void *to, void *from, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)` will NOT work for what I am trying to do, because it can only be called from outside of the kernel and does not execute asynchronously.**

Comment: You wrote "memcpy() doesn't work inside the kernel", but that isn't true, see my answer...

Comment: Also note that as of CUDA 6.0, `cudaMemcpy` is supported within device code for device-to-device copies.

Comment: @talonmies is it also possible to use cudaMemcpy for device-to-host copies?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, there is an equivalent to `memcpy` that works inside cuda kernels. It is called  `memcpy`. As an example:

```
__global__ void kernel(int **in, int **out, int len, int N)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    for(; idx<N; idx+=gridDim.x*blockDim.x)
        memcpy(out[idx], in[idx], sizeof(int)*len);

}
```

which compiles without error like this:

```
$ nvcc -Xptxas="-v" -arch=sm_20 -c memcpy.cu 
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelPPiS0_ii' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelPPiS0_ii
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 11 registers, 48 bytes cmem[0]
```

and emits PTX:

```
.version 3.0
.target sm_20
.address_size 32

    .file   1 "/tmp/tmpxft_00000407_00000000-9_memcpy.cpp3.i"
    .file   2 "memcpy.cu"
    .file   3 "/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/ci_include.h"

.entry _Z6kernelPPiS0_ii(
    .param .u32 _Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_0,
    .param .u32 _Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_1,
    .param .u32 _Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_2,
    .param .u32 _Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_3
)
{
    .reg .pred  %p<4>;
    .reg .s32   %r<32>;
    .reg .s16   %rc<2>;


    ld.param.u32    %r15, [_Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_0];
    ld.param.u32    %r16, [_Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_1];
    ld.param.u32    %r2, [_Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_3];
    cvta.to.global.u32  %r3, %r15;
    cvta.to.global.u32  %r4, %r16;
    .loc 2 4 1
    mov.u32     %r5, %ntid.x;
    mov.u32     %r17, %ctaid.x;
    mov.u32     %r18, %tid.x;
    mad.lo.s32  %r30, %r5, %r17, %r18;
    .loc 2 6 1
    setp.ge.s32     %p1, %r30, %r2;
    @%p1 bra    BB0_5;

    ld.param.u32    %r26, [_Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_2];
    shl.b32     %r7, %r26, 2;
    .loc 2 6 54
    mov.u32     %r19, %nctaid.x;
    .loc 2 4 1
    mov.u32     %r29, %ntid.x;
    .loc 2 6 54
    mul.lo.s32  %r8, %r29, %r19;

BB0_2:
    .loc 2 7 1
    shl.b32     %r21, %r30, 2;
    add.s32     %r22, %r4, %r21;
    ld.global.u32   %r11, [%r22];
    add.s32     %r23, %r3, %r21;
    ld.global.u32   %r10, [%r23];
    mov.u32     %r31, 0;

BB0_3:
    add.s32     %r24, %r10, %r31;
    ld.u8   %rc1, [%r24];
    add.s32     %r25, %r11, %r31;
    st.u8   [%r25], %rc1;
    add.s32     %r31, %r31, 1;
    setp.lt.u32     %p2, %r31, %r7;
    @%p2 bra    BB0_3;

    .loc 2 6 54
    add.s32     %r30, %r8, %r30;
    ld.param.u32    %r27, [_Z6kernelPPiS0_ii_param_3];
    .loc 2 6 1
    setp.lt.s32     %p3, %r30, %r27;
    @%p3 bra    BB0_2;

BB0_5:
    .loc 2 9 2
    ret;
}
```

The code block at `BB0_3` is a byte sized `memcpy` loop emitted automagically by the compiler. It might not be a great idea from a performance point-of-view to use it, but it is fully supported (and has been for a long time on all architectures).

---

Edited four years later to add that since the device side runtime API was released as part of the CUDA 6 release cycle, it is also possible to directly call something like

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(void *to, void *from, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)
```

in device code for all architectures which support it (Compute Capability 3.5 and newer hardware using separate compilation and device linking).

Comment: "It might not be a great idea from a performance point-of-view to use it". Do you mean that it would be better to use a for loop to copy every position of the array? If not can you tell for which possible array lengths it would be more efficient to copy with memcpy

Comment: Great -- I was worried that there would be function call overhead, but the folks at nVidia are smarter than that.

Answer (score 10):

In my testing the best answer is to write your own looping copy routine. In my case:

```
__device__
void devCpyCplx(const thrust::complex<float> *in, thrust::complex<float> *out, int len){
  // Casting for improved loads and stores
  for (int i=0; i<len/2; ++i) {
    ((float4*) out)[i] = ((float4*) out)[i];
  }
  if (len%2) {
    ((float2*) out)[len-1] = ((float2*) in)[len-1];
  } 
}
```

`memcpy` works in a kernel but it may be much slower. `cudaMemcpyAsync` from the host is a valid option.

I needed to partition 800 contiguous vectors of ~33,000 length to 16,500 length in different buffer with 1,600 copy calls. Timing with nvvp:

- memcpy in kernel: 140 ms
- cudaMemcpy DtoD on host: 34 ms
- loop copy in kernel: 8.6 ms

@talonmies reports that `memcpy` copies byte by byte which is inefficient with loads and stores. I'm targeting compute 3.0 still so I can't test cudaMemcpy on device.

**Edit:** Tested on a newer device. Device runtime `cudaMemcpyAsync(out, in, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice, 0)` is comparable to a good copy loop and better than a bad copy loop. Note using the device runtime api may require compile changes (sm>=3.5, separate compilation). Refer to [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#toolkit-support-for-dynamic-parallelism) and [nvcc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) docs for compiling.

Device `memcpy` bad. Host `cudaMemcpyAsync` okay. Device `cudaMemcpyAsync` good.

Answer (score 1):

`cudaMemcpy()` does indeed run asynchronously but you're right, it can't be executed from within a kernel.

Is the new shape of the array determined based on some calculation? Then, you would typically run the same number of threads as there are entries in your array. Each thread would run a calculation to determine the source and destination of a single entry in the array and then copy it there with a single assignment. (`dst[i] = src[j]`). If the new shape of the array is not based on calculations, it might be more efficient to run a series of `cudaMemcpy()` with `cudaMemCpyDeviceToDevice` from the host.