# What is a correct way to implement memcpy inside a CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda, numerical-methods

I am implementing a PDE solver ([Lax-Friedrichs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method)) in CUDA that I previously wrote in C. Please find the C code below:

```
void solve(int M, double u[M+3][M+3], double unp1[M+3][M+3], double params[3]){
 int i;
 int j;
 int n;


 for (n=0; n<params[0]; n++){
        for (i=0; i<M+2; i++)
           for(j=0; j<M+2; j++){
              unp1[i][j] = 0.25*(u[i+1][j] + u[i-1][j] + u[i][j+1] + u[i][j-1])
                 - params[1]*(u[i+1][j] - u[i-1][j])
                 - params[2]*(u[i][j+1] - u[i][j-1]);
           }
 
        memcpy(u, unp1, pow(M+3,2)*sizeof(double));
 
 
        /*Periodic Boundary Conditions*/
        for (i=0; i<M+2; i++){
           u[0][i] = u[N+1][i];
           u[i][0] = u[i][N+1];
           u[N+2][i] = u[1][i];
           u[i][N+2] = u[i][1];
        }
     }
  }
```

And it works fine. But when I am trying to implement it in CUDA I do not get the same data. Unfortunately I cannot exactly pinpoint the exact problem since I am a totally beginner to the whole parallel programming thing, but I think it might have to do with the `u[i*(N+3) + j] = unp1[i*(N+3) + j]` on the solver, since I cannot really perform a memcpy inside the kernel, because it doesn't change anything, I don't know how to proceed. I took a look at [This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456728/is-there-an-equivalent-to-memcpy-that-works-inside-a-cuda-kernel), but it unfortunately couldn't help solving my problem. Here is the solver in CUDA I am trying to code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

/*Configuration of the grid*/
const int N = 100; //Number of nodes  
const double xmin = -1.0;
const double ymin = -1.0;
const double xmax = 1.0;
const double ymax = 1.0;
const double tmax = 0.5;

/*Configuration of the simulation physics*/
const double dx = (xmax - xmin)/N;
const double dy = (ymax - ymin)/N;
const double dt = 0.009;
const double vx = 1.0;
const double vy = 1.0;


__global__ void initializeDomain(double *x, double *y){
    /*Initializes the grid of size (N+3)x(N+3) to better accomodate Boundary Conditions*/
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    for (int j=index ; j<N+3; j+=stride){
        x[j] = xmin + (j-1)*dx;
        y[j] = ymin + (j-1)*dy;
    }
}


__global__ void initializeU(double *x, double *y, double *u0){
    
    double sigma_x = 2.0;
    double sigma_y = 6.0;
    
    int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride_x = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int stride_y = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;
    
    for (int i = index_x; i < N+3; i += stride_x)
        for (int j = index_y; j < N+3; j+= stride_y){
            u0[i*(N+3) + j] = exp(-200*(pow(x[i],2)/(2*pow(sigma_x,2)) + pow(y[j],2)/(2*pow(sigma_y,2))));
            u0[i*(N+3) + j] *= 1/(2*M_PI*sigma_x*sigma_y);
               //u[i*(N+3) + j] = u0[i*(N+3) + j];
               //unp1[i*(N+3) + j] = u0[i*(N+3) + j];
    }
}


void initializeParams(double params[3]){
    params[0] = round(tmax/dt);
    params[1] = vx*dt/(2*dx);
    params[2] = vy*dt/(2*dy);
}


__global__ void solve(double *u, double *unp1, double params[3]){

     int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
     int stride_x = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
     int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
     int stride_y = blockDim.y * gridDim.y; 

     for (int i = index_x; i < N+2; i += stride_x)
          for (int j = index_y; j < N+2; j += stride_y){
               unp1[i*(N+3) + j] = 0.25*(u[(i+1)*(N+3) + j] + u[(i-1)*(N+3) + j] + u[i*(N+3) + (j+1)] + u[i*(N+3) + (j-1)]) \
               - params[1]*(u[(i+1)*(N+3) + j] - u[(i-1)*(N+3) + j]) \
               - params[2]*(u[i*(N+3) + (j+1)] - u[i*(N+3) + (j-1)]);
          }

}


__global__ void bc(double *u){
     int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
     int stride_x = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;


     /*Also BC are set on parallel */
     for (int i = index_x; i < N+2; i += stride_x){
          u[0*(N+3) + i] = u[(N+1)*(N+3) + i];
          u[i*(N+3) + 0] = u[i*(N+3) + (N+1)];
          u[(N+2)*(N+3) + i] = u[1*(N+3) + i];
          u[i*(N+3) + (N+2)] = u[i*(N+3) + 1];
     }
}


int main(){
     int i;
     int j;

     double *x = (double *)malloc((N+3)*sizeof(double));
     double *y = (double *)malloc((N+3)*sizeof(double));

     double *d_x, *d_y;
     cudaMalloc(&d_x, (N+3)*sizeof(double));
     cudaMalloc(&d_y, (N+3)*sizeof(double));

     initializeDomain<<<1, 1>>>(d_x, d_y);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();

     cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, (N+3)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, (N+3)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     FILE *fout1 = fopen("data_x.csv", "w");
    FILE *fout2 = fopen("data_y.csv", "w");

    for (i=0; i<N+3; i++){
        if (i==N+2){
            fprintf(fout1, "%.5f", x[i]);
            fprintf(fout2, "%.5f", y[i]);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(fout1, "%.5f, ", x[i]);
            fprintf(fout2, "%.5f, ", y[i]);
        }
    }


     dim3 Block2D(1,1);
     dim3 ThreadsPerBlock(1,1);

     double *d_u0;
     double *u0 = (double *)malloc((N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double));
     cudaMalloc(&d_u0, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double));

     initializeU<<<Block2D, ThreadsPerBlock>>>(d_x, d_y, d_u0);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     cudaMemcpy(u0, d_u0, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     /*Initialize parameters*/
     double params[3];
     initializeParams(params);

     /*Allocate memory for u and unp1 on device for the solver*/
     double *d_u, *d_unp1;
     cudaMalloc(&d_u, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double));
     cudaMalloc(&d_unp1, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double));
     cudaMemcpy(d_u, d_u0, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(d_unp1, d_u0, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
     
     /*Solve*/
     for (int n=0; n<params[0]; n++){
          solve<<<Block2D, ThreadsPerBlock>>>(d_u, d_unp1, params);
          double *temp = d_u;
          d_u = d_unp1;
          d_unp1 = temp;
          bc<<<1,1>>>(d_u);
          cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     }

     /*Copy results on host*/
     double *u = (double *)malloc((N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double));
     cudaMemcpy(u, d_u, (N+3)*(N+3)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     FILE *fu = fopen("data_u.csv", "w");
    for (i=0; i<N+3; i++){
          for(j=0; j<N+3; j++)
            if (j==N+2)
                fprintf(fu, "%.5f", u[i*(N+3) + j]);
            else
                fprintf(fu, "%.5f, ", u[i*(N+3) + j]);
        fprintf(fu, "\n");
    }
     fclose(fu);

     free(x);
     free(y);
     free(u0);
     free(u);
     cudaFree(d_x);
     cudaFree(d_y);
     cudaFree(d_u0);
     cudaFree(d_u);
     cudaFree(d_unp1);

     return 0;
}
```

I unfortunately keep having the same issue: The data I get is 0.0000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that is tripping you up is that your original algorithm has an ordering that is required for correctness:

1. Update `unp` from `u`
2. copy `unp` to `u`
3. enforce boundary condition
4. repeat

Your algorithm requires that step 1 be completed *entirely* before step 2 begins, and likewise for step 2 before step 3.  Your CUDA realization (putting steps 1 and 3, or 1,2,3) in a single kernel does not preserve or guarantee that ordering.  CUDA threads can execute *in any order*.  If you apply that rigorously to your code (for example, imagine that thread with index 0 executes *completely* before any other thread begins.  That would be valid CUDA execution) then you will see that your kernel design does not preserve the ordering required.

So do something like this:

1. Create a solve kernel that is just the first step:

   ```
    __global__ void solve(double *u, double *unp1, double params[3]){

         int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
         int stride_x = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
         int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
         int stride_y = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;

         for (int i = index_x; i < N+2; i += stride_x)
             for (int j = index_y; j < N+2; j += stride_y){
                  unp1[i*(N+3) + j] = 0.25*(u[(i+1)*(N+3) + j] + u[(i-1)*(N+3) + j] + u[i*(N+3) + (j+1)] + u[i*(N+3) + (j-1)]) \
                  - params[1]*(u[(i+1)*(N+3) + j] - u[(i-1)*(N+3) + j]) \
                  - params[2]*(u[i*(N+3) + (j+1)] - u[i*(N+3) + (j-1)]);
                  u[i*(N+3) + j] = unp1[i*(N+3) + j];
             }
    }
   ```
2. don't bother with the `memcpy` operation.  the better way to do that is swapping pointers (in *host code*).
3. Create a separate kernel to enforce the boundary:

   ```
    __global__ void bc(double *u, double *unp1, double params[3]){

         int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
         int stride_x = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
         int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
         int stride_y = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;
         /*Also BC are set on parallel */
         for (int i = index_x; i < N+2; i += stride_x){
              u[0*(N+3) + i] = u[(N+1)*(N+3) + i];
              u[i*(N+3) + 0] = u[i*(N+3) + (N+1)];
              u[(N+2)*(N+3) + i] = u[1*(N+3) + i];
              u[i*(N+3) + (N+2)] = u[i*(N+3) + 1];
         }
    }
   ```
4. Modify your host code to call these kernels in sequence, with the pointer swap in-between:

   ```
      /*Solve*/
      for(int n = 0; n<params[0]; n++){
           solve<<<Block2D, ThreadsPerBlock>>>(d_u, d_unp1, params);
           double *temp = d_u;
           d_u = d_unp1;
           d_unp1 = temp;
           bc<<<Block2D, ThreadsPerBlock>>>(d_u, d_unp1, params);
           cudaDeviceSynchronize();
      }
   ```

(coded in browser, not tested)

This will enforce the ordering that your algorithm requires.

NOTE: As identified in the comments below, the `solve` kernel as depicted above (and in OP's original post, and in their posted CPU code version) has indexing errors at least associated with `i-1` and `j-1` indexing patterns.  These should be fixed otherwise the code is **broken**.  Fixing them requires some decision as to what to do for the edge cases, which OP provides no guidance on, therefore I have left that code as-is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I understand what you mean. Unfortunately, I still get only 0.0000 as data points though. I edited out the line `u[i*(N+3) + j] = unp1[i*(N+3) + j];` on the kernel solve() (because I imagine this would defeat the purpose of the swap-in) and created the bc kernel as you advised (using only a 1D block, so on the host code it is now `bc<<<1,1>>>(d_u)`. I edited the first post for clarification, you can find the EDIT at the end of the post

Comment: I can't debug a partial code for you.  If you are asking for debugging assistance (rather than what to do about `memcpy`) you are supposed to provide a  [mcve].  See item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), note use of the word "must".

Comment: I would also encourage you to use [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your code with `compute-sanitizer`.

Comment: I updated my first post with a reproducible example in case you would like to compile it. As it can be seen, I start having problems from the solve() kernel onwards. Before that, I get the correct data. Thanks again!

Comment: Run your code with `compute-sanitizer` like I suggested.   Even better, first compile with `-lineinfo`.  Your `solve` kernel is making illegal, out-of-bounds accesses (global reads) at this line: `unp1[i*(N+3) + j] = 0.25*(u[(i+1)*(N+3) + j] + u[(i-1)*(N+3) + j] + u[i*(N+3) + (j+1)] + u[i*(N+3) + (j-1)]) ...`  It seems fairly evident to me that `i-1` will give illegal indexing for the threads whose `i` value starts at 0.  likewise for `j-1` indexing.  You might want to fix your CPU code also.

Comment: True. This is indeed the problem. I just fixed that and mark your solution as valid. Thanks.